# Create a presence with no type in Smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm having trouble finding a way to create a presence with no type in Smack. The presence class is final and I can't simply subclass it.

The reason why I need a presence with no type is so I can use it to join a MultiUserChat with an element added to the presence, which I can do in Smack version 4.2.0 with the `MucEnterConfiguration` class.

Comment: in theory you can customize your Presence by adding an  ExtensionElement in place of define custom Type or whatever https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.4/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/ExtensionElement.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Presence.Type.available`, which is also the default type, no type will be sent with the actual Stanza. (It's only for clarification within the Framework)